# Xcode 3.2 offline documentation?

Tags: xcode, offline

I've upgraded to Xcode 3.2 and I'm searching for the offline documentation / reference library that was always available for the previous versions of Xcode.

When I go to menu Help -> Developer Documentation I get the reference library but when I search for any term like NSViewController the pop up keeps showing up (annoyingly) telling me that I'm not connected to internet -> which I know because I'm not ...

Does it mean I'm not longer able to look at documentation when I'm not connected to internet?

I'm missing the introductory topics on various technologies and so on like Window Controller and so on. Is there a place to download any additional offline documentation for Xcode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's in Preferences > Documentation.

Comment: Oh I see it ... the last item in preferences

Comment: In 4.5 at least, it's in Organizer > Documentation

Answer (score 4):

The documentation view in XCode should allow you to download the documentation sets, so that they're available for off-line reading. You'll find them installed in /Developer/Documentation/DocSets although for the iPhone stuff, it'll be in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets.

If you look at the source of http://developer.apple.com/rss/adcdocsets.atom (it won't show up in Safari, you'll have to use 'curl' or 'wget') then you can find the archives to download in 'xar' format. The command line 'xar -x' should be able to extract them.